# How to read nodejs console.log data in nginx server

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, nginx

If I am running an application in Nodejs such as

```
const name = 'James'
console.log(name)
```

And I push this code to my digitalocean nginx server.

How can I read the console data in nginx

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by reading the console in nginx? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: for instance, i am trying to debug, and i need to log a variable to see what it is contained in it.

Comment: Just look at the output of the node process.  If it's running in a docker container, you can look at the docker container logs.  If it's not running in a docker container, then you'll have to tell us what you did with the stdout of the node process when you started it.

Comment: the issue I am actually having is this [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389490/websocket-socket-io-works-on-my-local-machine-but-not-on-nginx ) @EricQvarnström

Comment: @merlin If you want to see the error output, try get the hold of some log files. If you cant get access to any, install a logger package and set it up to save errors ets :) Watching the error output cannot be done via nginx.

Comment: Any particular answer for this? I just want to see my console.log() from nodejs runnding via nginx on ubuntu server. where should can i find them?